# What happens to the remaining 1px when a div with an odd width is split 50%/50%?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I wanted to make a background for `div#wrapper` so that half is blue and half is red using two divs with `width:50%`, like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftSide"></div>
    <div id="rightSide"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html, #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    background: white;
}

#leftSide, #rightSide {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#leftSide {
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}

#rightSide {
    float: right;
    background: red;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle for the above example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9tMck/)

This would theoretically solve the task. However, if the wrapper had a width containing an odd number of pixels, what would happen to the remaining 1px?

For example, if the wrapper's width were changed to 101px, then `#leftSide` would be 50px wide, and `#rightSide` would be 50px wide, presumably leaving a 1px vertical white line running down the middle.

How do browsers normally render this? Will one of the sides absorb the remaining 1px? And, if so, what would be the best pure CSS approach to working around this? My first inclination would be to set the background of the wrapper to either red or blue, but are there other approaches?

Comment: I would have thought the right hand side would gain a pixel, or the last one on the right wouldn't have any background colour.

Comment: The proverbial coin flip. This is why 1px shifts occur in browsers, and differently in different browsers. There is no "normal".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/dq323/.

In IE and Firefox, the right side takes up the extra pixel. In Chrome, there's actually a gap between the two.

Setting the background of the container seems like the best way to address this.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is not set a width to the second `DIV` (`#rightSide`) and set `float: left;` only on the left `DIV`. Since these are block elements, they will always expand to the full available width if none was set.

In the example, the wrapper width is 3px, the left container has a width of 1-2px (depending on the browser) and the right container will require the leftover horizontal space inside the wrapper:

http://jsfiddle.net/dq323/1/

Comment: May anybody tell me, what is wrong with that perfectly valid solution?