# Strange border on "cover" backgrounds inside elements with display table-cell css property - Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm seeing 1px border/gap between columns on some resolutions in chrome:

[image]

there's no gap in Firefox btw.

```css
.row.equalize {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.equalize [class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row equalize">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 wt-bg-two"></div>
  <!--div with bg image -->
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 c-dark-blue">
    <div class="inner text-right">
      <h3>Some Title</h3>
      <p>some paragraph text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/p3gx6ghj/)

Just open it in Chrome/Win - resize the result frame until boxes are side by side - the best example of what I'm trying to show can be viewed in the 2nd row - on some frame widths 1px gap appears.

IMPORTANT:
answers including "flex" solution would not be accepted, thx

Comment: add a fiddle / snippet too?

Comment: cool... post that as an answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is caused by an odd number of pixels that Bootstrap is trying to split 50/50 via `col-sm-6` class. See [What happens to the remaining 1px when a div with an odd width is split 50%/50%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673388/what-happens-to-the-remaining-1px-when-a-div-with-an-odd-width-is-split-50-50) for browser-specific details.

Comment: it appears this "solves" the problem:
"Setting the background of the container seems like the best way to address this."

@dpfrakes
Thank You for pointing to this one