# How do half pixels in browser correlate to JavaScript clientWidth / clientHeight?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I have a container element (using grid or flex layout) with an uneven height (e.g. 201 px) and put two other elements inside that equally split element the Chrome developer tools shows me that each height of those elements is exactly half in size (100.5 px). But when I get the `clientWidth` of those elements using JavaScript those are rounded to 100px resp. 101px.

When I now put some other elements in those elements again (with width and height set to 100%) those show both 101px. Is this a bug in the layout engine? (see console of [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lbnrp24/)). Is there an easy way to fix this?

**Additional note** I more wondering why the inner elements do report both 101px when the outer elements report 100 resp. 101 px.

Comment: I would believe that the JavaScript `clientWidth` is rounding the numbers. If you should round 100.5, you would round up to 101.

Comment: Why would you think it's a bug? You're trying to split a 401px box in 2. One of the boxes should get that other pixel.

Comment: @rblarsen If that was the case, then it would round both numbers up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to the remaining 1px when a div with an odd width is split 50%/50%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673388/what-happens-to-the-remaining-1px-when-a-div-with-an-odd-width-is-split-50-50)

Comment: The thing is I am more wondering about why the inner elements then report both 101 px as those are defined as 100% width and height?!

Answer (score 5):

According to the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#extension-to-the-element-interface), `clientHeight` (and related properties) should be type `long` (an integer), so JS engines return a rounded integer value. The layout information is still available though, and if you want the exact pixels, you should use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method. [The MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) also recommends using this if you need a fractional value.

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lbnrp24/3/) which now shows the half-pixels:

```
Outer rects:
200.5
200.5
Inner rects:
200.5
200.5
```